# Is it normal that my adviser remove my information, pictures, everything from the lab homepage after I suspend my school?

Tags: graduate-school, advisor, lab-management

First of all, I studied in Japan. After I complete all graduate courses. There will be 3 years to submit my thesis. During this time, I drop school and work in a company. So my professor removed all my information from the lab (%100) like I was not there, even Alumni name list. I would like to ask is it common for other schools.

Comment: @Drecate: Normally students working on their dissertation want to discuss their work with their peers... it's not good when the lab website undermines their claims of doing research in such-and-such group.

Comment: Where in the 3 year period are you? Are you going to complete your thesis? Are you still in regular touch? Does your adviser know where you are, what you are doing, and how to get in touch with you? If you just stopped showing up and aren't in regular contact, what exactly did you expect would happen?

Comment: The university doesn't require you to be enrolled while working on your dissertation? Todai appears to allow up to a 1 year absence only, as an example.Are you on an official leave of absence?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable in its current form, OP needs to clarify his current status in the program and the school.

Answer (score 6):

Consider your relationship with the professor at the time that you left. There are at least two cases I can think of where a professor may remove your information from the lab page.

- You didn't finish, and you are no longer part of the lab (not quite alumni). It's not clear if you will finish. A lot of unfinished students can make a bad reputation for the prof.
- The professor does not want you to represent the lab.

As you probably know, Asian culture is a lot about 'saving face'. The professor may feel disrespected by you taking a job before finishing the thesis. Or possibly even taking the 'wrong' job.

One place that the professor is very, very unlikely to remove your name is the lab publications list. Work on publication, and use that as your work reference rather than the lab webpage.

If possible, try to discuss your research with the professor.

Comment: I'd even put it more strongly: OP is neither a current student nor a graduate, therefore it is correct to not list him/her as one.

Answer (score 3):

It's normal to remove old student content from the group page.  Get your own page if you want.

I'm not as used to seeing ABD or "got masters and quit" students removed from alumni list.  Most professors want to emphasize how many students they have helped and take credit even for those who did not finish.  However, it's still a very minor thing, and "his dojo" and not your concern.

Really, I think worrying about stuff like group inclusion when you are gone is a little "off".  I mean you left the nest...you shouldn't even be snooping that page...or at least act like you are above it.  ;-)  Keep your eye on the current job who is paying you.  And just submit the thesis and fight to get your union card...don't let it get away.  Priorities...